# Rotating screen in ios10

Tags: ios, swift3, ios10

**Just sometimes**

After update to swift3.0 and update ios10, When I enter a need horizontal screen 'viewController', Sometimes appear such result like this:
[image]

Before used is normal,
It should be correct like that:
[image]

I don't know this is a bug or I need to do some change

this is 'swift' code:

```
override var shouldAutorotate : Bool {
return true }

override var supportedInterfaceOrientations : UIInterfaceOrientationMask   {
return .landscape }

override var preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation : UIInterfaceOrientation {
return .landscapeLeft }
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what happens and what you want to achieve: You want to force the app to be in landscape mode even if it is held in portrait mode? But if you hold it in portrait mode, it works as shown in the first image, i.e. it is in portrait mode but the layout is as if for landscape mode?

Comment: It Need to horizontally，When it has no horizontal, press the home button and enter the app， it will be OK（horizontal）

Comment: It would be interesting to understand what has changed with iOS 10. Otherwise reliable commerical apps (e.g. YouTube or Microsoft Office Lens) sometimes show the same behavior since I've upgraded my devices to iOS 10.

Comment: Thinks ,You mean this is iOS10‘s bug , I don't need to do some change

Comment: I also think this is an iOS 10 bug, it occured on my iPhone with Apple Mail.